# Only first entry from loop being entered into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data into a MySQL table using information from a form. For some reason, only the first entry is being inserted into the table.

How can I resolve this issue? Thanks

[MySQL table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rzSL.png)

```
....
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$makeArr = $_POST['make'];
$modelArr = $_POST['model'];
$yearArr = $_POST['year'];
$regoArr = $_POST['rego'];
if(!empty($makeArr)){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($makeArr); $i++){
        if(!empty($makeArr[$i])){
            $make = $makeArr[$i];
            $model = $modelArr[$i];
            $year = $yearArr[$i];
            $rego = $regoArr[$i];

          //database insert query goes here 

                $sql = "INSERT INTO test (`make`, `model`, `year`, `rego`) VALUES ('$make', '$model', '$year', '$rego')";

                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    echo "New record created successfully";
                } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                }

                $conn->close();                 

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do not close the connection within the loop

Comment: Please think carefully about this code - it is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: `foreach` loops are easier to read if you're struggling with looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing `$conn` within your for loop. You should take it and put it outside the for loop.

`$conn->close()` will close the sql connection.

This means it can't be used again.